# filtering out the list data if the attributes are null itself

Tags: java, java-5

I have the below class named BrokerInvoice which contain the following member variables

```
public class BrokerInvoice
{
private  List<BrokerInvoiceLineItem> lineItems;

//and its corresponding setters and getters 

}
```

I have the below java class named BrokerInvoiceLineItem as shown below  which has a relationship among the top class named brokerInvoice as the below class is added in the to class as a list

```
public class BrokerInvoiceLineItem {

    private String brokerRefId;
    private double notional;
    private Date dealDate;


    //corresponding setters and getters

    }
```

now in some piece of code i am getting the object of parent class that is of broker invoice itself

```
 BrokerInvoice  brokerInvoice1 = abc.findrty( brokerIdLong , serType );
```

now the above brokerInvoice1 object contain the entries of lineItems that is of type BrokerInvoiceLineItem  also , so i  want to edit the  list named lineitems such that the list i am getting inside the  brokerInvoice1 object  as  the condition is that there should be a sort of pre check that if lineitems list attributes named brokerRefId,notional,dealDate,dealDate are null then that entry should not be there in the line items list itself

so please advise how can i filter out my lineitems list residing inside brokerInvoice1 object such that there should not be no null attribute entry inside the lineitemslist if these attribute are empty

I am using Java 5 please advise how to achieve this can I achieve the same by java5

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Java 8 you can use `removeIf` from [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
listItems.removeIf(i -> i.getBrokerRefId() == null || i.getDealDate() == null);
```

This assuming you want to mutate the list.
If you prefer to not change the `listItems`, and only get a new list without the wrong items, you can use [stream filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
List<BrokerInvoiceLineItem> newList = listItems.stream()
    .filter(i -> i.getBrokerRefId() != null)
    .filter(i -> i.getDealDate() != null)
    .collect(Collector.toList());
```

Notice, that the stream version retains items that match the predicate and the `removeIf` one does the opposite, so the predicates are inverted.

Comment: Thanks a lot perfect explanation I amusing java 5 request you to please advise how to achieve this with Jasper a 5

Answer (score 0):

Java 5 :

```
private  List<BrokerInvoiceLineItem> newLineItems = new ArrayList<BrokerInvoiceLineItem>();


if (brokerInvoice1 != null && brokerInvoice1.lineItems != null){
for(BrokerInvoiceLineItem brokerInvoiceLineItem : brokerInvoice1.lineItems){
    if(brokerInvoiceLineItem.getBrokerRefId() != null && brokerInvoiceLineItem.getDealDate() == null){
        newLineItems.add(brokerInvoiceLineItem)
    }
}
```

}